# Why is importing module not working when running the code for the second time

Tags: python

I am quite new to Python. I'm using version 3.7.
I am trying to understand how modules work.
How is it possible that once I import a module, the code is executed as planned. However, when I try to re-run the same code, there are no results?
When I restart the kernel and run (again) the code, the code in the module is executed. Why does it not work the second time?

I am using the following files:

MainFile.ipynb
ABC.py

The 'MainFile.ipynb' is an empty Jupyter notebook.
The 'ABC.py' contains the below code:

```
print('this is module ABC')
```

When I write the below code in the 'MainFile.ipynb' Jupyter notebook:

```
import ABC
```

I get the following result (when running it the first time):

```
this is module ABC
```

However, when I try to re-run it the second time, I don't see any result. As it the code wouldn't run.

When I restart the kernel and run the `import ABC` command, I get the `this is module AB`C as result.

Comment: You need to provide us the code that you are using.

Comment: Python won't import the same module twice. On jupyter notebook you need to restart the kernel to reload the modules. You can use the "auto reload" magic in some specific cases https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html?highlight=reload%20import#autoreload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python will only execute imports once, since a lot of the imports such as `os` are likely done hundreds or thousands of times inside other libraries, and it'd be very inefficient to execute the code each time. You *could* probably reload the import, but it's bad practice to run code directly in a file anyway, which it sounds like you're trying to do.

Instead of this:

```
# myfile.py

with open('x.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('test')
```

It's better to do something like this:

```
# myfile.py

def main():
    with open('x.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then from the console, instead of `import myfile`, you can use `from myfile import main`, then you can call `main()` as many times as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
# `module.py`

print("Hello!")
```

In the REPL:

```
~/t/py_proj $ python
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 18 2021, 12:31:01) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import module
Hello!
>>> import module # nothing happens?
>>> import module # nothing happens!
>>>
```

Apparently, the module isn't executed each time you `import module`. In fact, when you run this for the first time in a directory that contains nothing but `module.py`, you'll see a new directory called `__pycache__` appear in that directory:

```sh
~/t/py_proj $ ls -R
__pycache__ module.py

./__pycache__:
module.cpython-39.pyc
```

Python caches code and modules that you import for performance reasons: you *don't* want to import heavy modules multiple times because that would take too much time.